# Google App Script - Display PDF on Form Submit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a current Google Form and App Script where the Apps Script is taking the form data, putting it into a spreadsheet template (which does some calculations) then e-mails that spreadsheet as a PDF.

Is there a way in Google Apps Script to have this PDF displayed in the web browser rather than being sent in an e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [workround](https://script.google.com/d/1ykLVsEIOqdalF7izAvSXvuCw_IWjuPg4ygEex1eKMT9ueHp0bRh9zCiS/edit?usp=sharing)  .

**pag.html**

```
<html>
<input type="submit" onclick="downloadPDF()"/>  
<a href="#" id="myDownloadLink" style="display:none">Click here to open</a>

<script>
  function sucess(e) {
   alert(e);
   var downloadLink = document.getElementById("myDownloadLink");  
   downloadLink.href=e;
   downloadLink.style.display = 'block';    
}

function downloadPDF() {
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(alert).withSuccessHandler(sucess).getFile();
}
</script>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("pag");
}

function getFile() {
  return DriveApp.getFileById("1pczv0kRvgpI87owXWUXTtm4wXXsiG8-ErVWFtv05izI").getUrl();
}
```

Comment: @braraujo From where do we get this ID "1pczv0kRvgpI87owXWUXTtm4wXXsiG8-ErVWFtv05izI"?