# Serve PDF file as blob in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that generates a PDF file. My goal now is to serve that PDF file back to the UI so the user can download or print it. However, the limitation here is that I cannot redirect the user to a Google Drive URL - I need the file to be given to the user on the same page that initiated the file generation. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072944/google-app-script-display-pdf-on-form-submit) which gives a solution to download, but it uses a Google Drive link. Additionally, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021597/how-to-download-created-csv-file-using-google-apps-script) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281272/initiate-a-download-from-google-apps-script?noredirect=1&lq=1) mention downloading, but it only works for the given file types, which does not include PDF.

I am able to generate the PDF and blob inside the [`doGet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) method, but I don't know how to serve it to the UI so the user can then interact with is. Is there a way to pass the blob to the front end and then allow the user to download or print that blob as a PDF?

```
function doGet(request){    
    var file = generateFile();
    var blob = file.getAs('application/pdf');
    //Goal: return blob to front end so user can download / print
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by passing the data down as a base64 encoded file. I used [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getBytes()) to get the file as an array of bytes, and then [base64encode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata) to encode it before sending it down the front end. On the front-end side, I used a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415665/save-base64-string-as-pdf-at-client-side-with-javascript) to allow the user to download the file.

Comment: Could you add code example to your answer?  I tried following those but I get error `document is not defined` or `window is not defined`